# attest to centuries of cross-pollination

Tags: word-meaning

Does "attest" here mean "witness"?

Plus, I am not very clear what "as the beliefs" means. Does "as" mean "because" here?

> The Myth of "Moderation" in Religion The idea that any one of our religions represents the infallible word of the One True God requires an encyclopedic ignorance of history, mythology, and art even to be entertained—**as the beliefs**, rituals, and iconography of each of our religions **attest to centuries of cross-pollination** among them.

> Source: The End of Faith by Sam Harris (PDF)

Comment: Have you looked up _attest_ in the dictionary? It has its usual meaning - 'serve as evidence of'.

Comment: Of course I have. The problem is that the "attest" is followed by "to". Without "to",  "serve as evidence of (centuries of cross-pollination among them)" - that is okay.  But how do you put "to"?  Plus, does "as" in "as the beliefs, rituals, and iconography" mean "because"?

Comment: Most online dictionaries give examples of the same sense of _attest_ used with and without _to_.

Comment: I knew. I checked out them and still failed to satisfactorily analyze the case in the OP.

Comment: Yes, "as" means "because". *Attest to* means as Kate has said. Evidence *attests to* (whatever it says). Sam Harris' statements *attest to* a penchant for gross generalizations. You get the idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *attest* can be used with and without *to*.

The word *as* can be replaced here by *because*, and *beliefs* is part of a noun phrase with *rituals* and *iconography*.
So, the sentence you question means

> ... because the [beliefs, rituals and iconography] of each our religions...